# Ubuntu Stays on Desktop BackGround Picture

Tags: 14.04

When I turn my PC on it works until bacground picture comes.
But than nothing comes.
No desktop icons,
no upper line settings,
no left short-cut icons. Nothing.

I can move mouse pointer on an empty screen but can do nothing with my keyboard.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> does not work,
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work,
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>  does not work...

I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu and format my PC.

Hope smeone would help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to rest the settings:

- Press Ctrl+Alt+F2.
- You will get a login prompt with a black screen. Login to your account.
- Execute this command:

> sudo rm -r .*
>   sudo reboot now
>
> ## Warning!

This will erase your application settings, including Firefox history and bookmarks.

Comment: This made desktop backround picture to default Ubuntu pic. Probably made whole settings default. But did not solved my problem. Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to turn the Unity plugin back on.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Install the jibby you'll need to configure the settings by running this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
3. Then run it by doing this:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ccsm
   ```

   The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes) to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager screen sitting there.
5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it.
6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to TTY1 and running `sudo reboot`.

Comment: After 3rd step there was writing "icons showing" or sth like that than Ctrl+Alt+F7 passed to graphical screen. I enabled "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" & morever needs to be enabled with it. Than i clicked "close". No change. Than again i clicked "CTRL+Alt+F1" and gave "sudo reboot" command but after restarting ONLY DESKTOP SHORT-CUT icons came. But in my PC everyting in a normal ubuntu screen is lost. On the Left Ubuntu Programs Menü, on the top the line with "settings, clock-time, wireless" etc. Can it be because i uninstall "fglrx-updates" driver and install manually from AMD site graphic driver?

Comment: ayibugan: Can be. The best way to check it is to remove the AMD proprietary driver.  `sudo apt-get remove fglrx-updates`. Then install the open source driver: `sudo apt-get install xf86-video-ati`

Comment: I entered these commands on Ctrl+Alt+F1. But still not working. I'll reinstall ubuntu when i've time. Thanks.